TLS communication inside pod
I have a pod with two containers: c1 and c2, c2 is the sidecar. c1 is running in tls, c2 communicates to c1 using TLS.
c1 and c2 could share the same certificate. What  CN or SAN should the certificate?
I have tried:

pod name: the pod name might change if the sts scale out, such as pod-0, pod-1, pod-2. a wildcard should work, but it brings out potential security issue.
service name: this does not work, it cannot identify c1.
localhost: this is working as c1 and c2 shares the same pod resource, but this brings out potential security issues.

Any other solution for this?

but it bring out some potential security issue what issue?

if CN is set as "localhost" or the SAN includes "localhost", it should match too many servers.

What's the security issue with using the pod name in the SAN?

@GregAskew there might be more than 1 pod in the sts, how t handle this, wildcard?

The name that you are connecting to needs to be listed in the SAN. The CN isn't as important. Have a look at Amazon website sometime, it may have 50 names.

Ok, I will have a try to list all of the possible pod names in the SAN, 3 maybe, 5 at most

Containers within the same pod share the same networking namespace. As such, localhost on one container = localhost on the other. This is what you could potentially use.
Having said that, it is extremely unusual to see TLS being employed to protect communication between two containers inside the same pod, and not something I'd typically recommend. Your question doesn't explain why would that be needed and what are the potential security issues you are trying to mitigate.
For secure communication between pods you can use TLS provided by solutions like Istio service mesh. It will automatically handle certificates for you.

Actually, c1 is memcached and c2 is memcached-exporter. c1 is configured with TLS and c2 collects the metrics of c1 with TLS too.
